# Convert Natural Earth shape to GeoJSON - (Multi)LineString instead of (Multi)Polygon?

Tags: gdal, convert, ogr2ogr, natural-earth

I need shapes of admin regions as GeoJSON (Multi)Polygons. After looking for an appropriate source for way too long, I found [this NE Admin 1](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-1-states-provinces/) dataset.

Using `ogr2ogr` to convert the data to GeoJSON, I found features with geometry-type `(Multi)LineString`. Not quite what I wanted. [This guy on GitHub](https://github.com/LonnyGomes/CountryGeoJSONCollection/tree/master/geojson) used a different dataset from Natural Earth, but he got `(Multi)Polygons`. Are there some special options for `ogr2ogr`, some possible conversions, or is it the dataset?

I need to determine whether a point is in a province/region and with the tools I'm using, that's easiest with polygons. If it happens to be a problem with the dataset, does anyone know an alternative?

That's the command I used for conversion:

ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs crs:84 output.geojson ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_lines.shp`

PS: Most examples I've found specify `-t_srs crs:84`. I do need `WGS84`, as I'm also using data from geonames.org. But I'm not sure if I even need the transformation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clue is in the name :-) You downloaded [`boundary lines`](http://http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces_lines.zip) when infact you wanted to use [`States and Provinces`](http://http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/10m/cultural/ne_10m_admin_1_states_provinces.zip) which is a polygon layer.

Comment: Begginer mistake, we all went through this (secretly)

Comment: Awww, man I'm embarrassed ^^ I thought 'lines' means just the outlines, the shapes and the other one contains more data x) ty!

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your *Post Scriptum*: You already use the right projection. CRS:84 is synonymous to the EPSG-Code: 4326, which is the Coordinate-Reference-System known as: WSG84.

You can always use EPSG-Codes instead of CRS-Names. EPSG-Codes are not so ambiguous in my opinion.

In your Example, the transform-srs-parameter (`-t_srs`) would look like this: `-t_srs EPSG:4326`

Oh, and by the way: you dont need to retransform, when your dataset already has the right projection. So using the set-SRS parameter (`-s_srs`) would be appropriate in your example.

Comment: As far as I see, Natural Earth shapefiles are already in WGS84, so no need to transform.

Comment: @AndreJ: You are right. Just edited my answer.

Comment: You don't even need the -s_srs, because that is in the .prj file. And -s_srs without -t_srs would do nothing (no target defined, hence no reprojection).